# How to make a new HashMap containing only elements accepted by the filter?

Tags: rust

I'm trying this:

```rust
let map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(1, "foo");
map.insert(2, "bar");
let map2 = map.into_iter().filter(|k, v| k > 1).collect(); // doesn't compile
```

```
error[E0593]: closure is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 2 arguments
 -->
  |
  | let map2 = map.into_iter().filter(|k, v| k > 1).collect(); // doesn't compile
  |                            ^^^^^^ ------ takes 2 arguments
  |                            |
  |                            expected closure that takes 1 argument
```

I need `map2` to be a new map, not an iterator over `map`. What is the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems. Here's working code.

```
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert(1, "foo");
map.insert(2, "bar");
let map2: HashMap<_, _> = map.into_iter().filter(|(k, v)| *k > 1).collect();
```

1. `map` is not mutable. So you cannot insert element to `map`.
2. For filter, the argument function must have only one argument. So instead of taking `k` and `v` as argument, take the tuple `(k, v)` as argument.
3. When compiler can't infer the collection type, you need to give a type when you use function `collect`.